# Get pre-existing variable through user input

Tags: python-3.6

I'm making a script that asks for input. Few variables has been set according to number of option.

```
option1 = '.\\Folder'
userChoice = input()
def func(userChoice):
   pyautogui.locateOnScreen(userChoice)
```

But if user type option1 then userChoice = 'option1' instead '.\Folder' which lead to 'No such file or directory' error.
How could i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `try-except`. An example from official docs:

```
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert data to an integer.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

**Update**: Based on your comment, I think you need to do something like this:

```
choices={'option1' : './/Folder'}
userChoice = input()
try:
    function=choices[userChoice]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError('invalid input')
```

Comment: i mean i want the script to recieve variable instead the str type of it. Then when user typed "option1", it would be pyautogui.locateOnScreen('.\\Folder') instead ('option1')

Comment: @PhucVuong I have updated the answer, check if it works.